# js-joda format with javascript

Tags: formatter, js-joda

this is my code, Is there a more effective solution?
I have tried format with pattern "HH:mm:ss a", but it not working

```
`// import lib
import { LocalDateTime, DateTimeFormatter } from "@js-joda/core";

// create date by string
const date = LocalDateTime.parse("2012-12-24T23:00:11.123123");

// format with 24h type
const dateStr1 = date.format(
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss")
);

// format with 12h type
const dateStr2 = date.format(
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss")
);

// get result and plus "am" or "pm"
if (dateStr1 === dateStr2) {
  console.log(dateStr2 + " am");
} else {
  console.log(dateStr2 + " pm");
}`
```

have a best resolution